# How I can set typeface (font) of this spinner text?

Tags: android, fonts, spinner, dropdown, typeface

I don't understand why I don't set the font for this spinner-text in a form activity.

[IMAGE](https://i.ibb.co/gv6P6wR/device-2019-08-27-083933.png)

```
private void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    colorescelto = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
}



private void addItemsOnSpinner() {
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.colorchoose);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.colori, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}



// get the selected dropdown list value
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.colorchoose);
}





<Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/colorchoose"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/datanascita"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:entries="@array/colori"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextcentro"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/scuro"
                    android:prompt="@string/colorescelta"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

I want to set all these texts with the same non-default font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by-:

Just make a different layout my_layout-

```
<Textview
   fontFamily="your font family"

</Textview>
```

and just change the code from-:

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.colori, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

to-:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.colori, R.layout.my_layout);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_layout);
```

Comment: Your method works for me :)
Thanks!

https://i.ibb.co/P4sQvk8/photo-2019-08-29-10-08-53.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

In spinner adapter, add item text typeface like

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.item_layout_spinner, null);
    TextView textView= view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setTextSize(13);
    Typeface avnier_roman = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "AvenirLTStd-Roman.otf");
    textView.setTypeface(avnier_roman);
    return view;
}
```